# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' (have tried other answers)

Tags: php

I'm using a php book and after 3 hours setting up apache i'm stuck fairly early on and really can't see my issue here, this code outputs the error in the title:

```
<?php
// create short variable names
$tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’];
$oilqty = $_POST[‘oilqty’];
$sparkqty = $_POST[‘sparkqty’];
echo ‘<p>Your order is as follows: </p>’;
echo $tireqty.’ tires<br />’;
echo $oilqty.’ bottles of oil<br />’;
echo $sparkqty.’ spark plugs<br />’;
?>
```

I've tried taking the greater than less than symbols away and I just get a different error.
Sorry this seems like a very simple issue but i've been stuck forever.

Comment: You have some funky apostrophes. Change `’` and `‘` and all others to this: `'`

Comment: Try replacing your ticks, `’`, with single apostrophes, `'`. What are you doing to write code? You should use something made for code to avoid these problems.

Comment: Hint: Are them single quotes or backquotes?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Microsoft Word to edit your code:

```
$tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’];
                  ^-------^-----
```

"Smartquotes", aka truly-stupid-quotes, mean absolutely NOTHING to PHP.

Comment: I hate "smartquotes".